# MySQL result doesn't replace variables

Tags: php

I'm creating a language file - content modifying file - for my website so that I can change text over multiple websites in my admin panel.  I have everything working except one thing.  When I use a standard `lang.php` file with the contents like this:

```
$error_page_title = "$sitename | PAGE ERROR";
```

and use

```
<? echo $error_page_title ?>
```

I get:

example.com | PAGE ERROR to appear on my website.  Perfect, exactly what I want. Reflects the $sitename in my config file and outputs the correct website name.

When I do it as a function:

```
function langString($lang_id) {
$lang_result = mysql_query("SELECT lang_string as phrase FROM lang WHERE lang_id='$lang_id'");
$lang_row = mysql_fetch_array($lang_result); 
return $lang_row[phrase];
}
```

and use

```
<? echo langString(3); ?>
```

I get:

> $sitename | PAGE ERROR appearing on my website.  Not what I want... Arrr!

**How can I get it so that my output is recognized as PHP instead of text?**

Comment: ... You saved $sitename as a string in your database???

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Ben - yes I have multiple sites and sitename will reflect if I add that to a paragraph in a body of text over multiple sites.

Comment: String interpolation a feature of *string literals* and is not related to string data (such as the MySQL result).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace('$sitename', $sitename, langString(3));
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just reinvented 'template languages'.

Answer (score 0):

when using your function langString() instead of

```
return $lang_row[phrase];
```

use

```
return $lang_row['phrase'];
```

Also use `<?php` instead of `<?`, some servers cannot parse it correctly if you only use `<?`. probably not the problem, but never know